# How to go to next page when content exceeds page height

Tags: jakarta-ee, jasper-reports

I'm currently developping a J2EE webapp which generates pdf reports but there is a problem in the report and I can't figure out a way to fix it.  I don't know the length of the content that I've to print in the report so when it exceeds the page height, the page comes out blank. Is there a way or a parameter that is used to go to the next page when it exceeds page height?

FYI, the code has been done by other devs 2-3 years ago, the jrxml is created on the fly and I can't afford to refactor it in a cleaner way...  Also, the content isn't always generic, there is no pattern that can be extracted from it.

I don't know if what I ask is possible, but if it is I would be grateful if someone has the answer !

I don't know if it might help, but I pasted the jrxml on the jasperstudio and there is the type of problem that I encounter.

[image]

Have a nice day !

Comment: Have I understod correcly that you generate the .jrxml on the fly.... in image seems like a .jrxml with fields out of there band heights....... consider using Dynamc jasper?? Or maybe you have not grasped the .jrxml.. that you pass datasource to and it generates the pdf report on the basis of the datasource..

Comment: I think the problem is not understanding pake-break, but setting correct band-height if you added these fields..... not to be rude but I think you should study some more how jasper report works... What you are displaying is the template used to fill the report (it will be repeated on datasource), and the export will automatically do page break in the pdf..

Comment: First, thanks for answering ! You didn't sound rude at all :) As I said I inherited the project so I'm trying to do my best with what I got but I'll take a look to those page breaks and see if I can manage to place them. And yes you understood well, the app actually collects fields and their datas from the screen of the webapp (x,y,width,height) and just rewrite it in jrxml... and again I can't afford time to refactoring everything.. but then again thx for your time and that little hint on page break :)

Comment: Thanks, as I stated the problem is in the band height of the jaser report, so for now I belive you should not worry about the page break, but how to increase / set the correct band height...